# Crash when doubleclicking a button containing popModalAsync

Tags: c#, xamarin, button, xamarin.forms

When doubleclicking a button that executes the code

```
await Navigation.PopModalAsync(true);
```

the program enters break mode i.e. crashes. How should it be handled so it wont crash when spamclicking?

EDIT

I changed the parameter to false and it works as expected. Is there any workaround to keep the animation set on true?

SOLVED

simple solution:

```
Boolean _istapped = false;
    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_istapped)
            return;

        _istapped = true;

        await Navigation.PopModalAsync(true);

        _istapped = false;
    }
```

Comment: what exception is causing the crash?

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'  ---- I edited to false and it worked as expected. But is there any workaround to keep it on true?

Comment: have you tried catching the exception?

Comment: Solved the problem! thanks

Comment: @Jason Hi, Jason. Can you please help [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69939145/how-can-i-debug-a-libsc-and-i-have-source-code-in-a-xamarin-forms-project)?

Answer (score 0):

The app crash because when you double click the button, `Navigation.PopModalAsync` will execute twice and it can't find the page at the second time.

Here is another simple way to solve this problem:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    btn.IsEnabled = false;

    await Navigation.PopModalAsync(true);
    //btn.IsEnabled = true;
}
```