# How can I debug .a libs(c++ and I have source code) in a Xamarin.forms project?

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms project and there are also some .a libs(`C++`) referenced in Xamarin.iOS project.

```
Xamarin.Forms project

  ------codes

Xamarin.iOS project

  ------codes

  ------.a libs(c++)
```

I do have the **source code** of those .a `C++` libs.

The question is that is there a way that I can debug the C++ source code when running the Xamarin.forms project?

**Update**:

I just followed [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/debugging-with-xcode) and the Xcode does not attach to the Xamarin app when it launches. Any idea?

Comment: Xamarin-based Android apps w/ native libs can be debugged in VS on Windows (both C++ and C#), iOS presents a challenge as you need to configure your XCode project to deploy/launch your Xamarin.iOS app (basically you need to write a bash script that compiles/bundles/deploys your Xamarin `.app` after your XCode based lib is compiled, lots of XCode based blogs and SO q/a on this as Flutter, React, etc.. based apps all have to do do the same thing. You will not be able to debug your C++/C# code at the same time like you can do for Android apps on Windows

Comment: @SushiHangover I just followed [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/debugging-with-xcode) and the Xcode does not attach to the Xamarin app when it launches.

Comment: @SushiHangover `lots of XCode based blogs and SO q/a on this as Flutter`, can you please share me some relevant threads? Thanks!!!

Comment: Any `.a` library from iOS native imported to Xamarin only with [Binding Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/) and this will be generated as `.dll` library, so we can't debug it through Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot debug C++ in a xamarin.ios project, it is not supported and was confirmed by Microsoft's dev team.

Possible solution will be to mix objectiv-C and C++ code together in your xcode application.

Otherwise you will not be able to debug native code.

reference for help:

[Using native libraries in xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/cpp)

Answer (score 0):

`Xamarin.iOS` applications can be debugged with the **built-in** debugger in **Visual Studio for Mac** or **Visual Studio**.

`Xamarin.iOS` will generate slower and much larger applications as every line of code must be instrumented when you compile applications in Debug mode. Make sure that you do a Release build before releasing.

Use Visual Studio for Mac's native debugging support for debugging C# and other managed languages code and use **[LLDB](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/tutorial.html)** when you need to debug C, C++ or Objective C codethat you might be linking with your Xamarin.iOS project.

The Xamarin.iOS debugger uses the [Mono Soft Debugger](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/docs/soft-debugger/), which means that the generated code and the Mono runtime cooperate with the IDE to provide a debugging experience. This is different than hard debuggers like LLDB or MDB which control a program without the knowledge or cooperation from the debugged program.

Xamarin.iOS ships with the source code for Mono's class libraries, and you can use this to single step from the debugger to see how things are working under the hood.

> [image]To debug the class libraries in Visual Studio, you must disable Just My Code under the Debug > Options menu. In the Debugging > General node, clear the Enable Just My Code checkbox:

Please check this link for full debug tutorial: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/debugging-in-xamarin-ios?tabs=windows)